# Present continues meaning in special cases

Tags: grammar

"I'm wearing shoes".
Does it mean "I am putting on my shoes right now" or "My foots are in my shoes right now"?

Another example is 
"She is sitting on the table"

I usually am confused about the meaning of these kinds of sentences where doing the action doesn't take more than a moment. The action of "wearing" cannot be continued but it is used in present continuous form. Could anyone clarify this?

Answer (score 3):

*I am wearing shoes* unequivocally refers to my feet (not 'foots'!) being in my shoes. We use a different verb  - "put on" - for starting to wear clothes.

*Sit* is different, because the same verb can be used to the state and for the action that causes that state (though we often use the phrasal verb "sit down" for the action). But *wear* only refers to the state.

Comment: However, I am just wondering if the OP meant "on the table", or "at the table".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, English is frequently ambiguous, and "sitting" is a good example.  "She is sitting on the table" can either mean:

> She is **in the process of sitting down** on the table

or

> She is **currently seated** on the table.

This has nothing to do with the use of the present continuous. Instead it's a natural ambiguity of the verb "to sit" which has multiple interpretations in other tenses:

> "She **sat** on the table" =
>   1. She **was seated** on the table
>   2. She **moved to sit** on the table.

(Side note:  To be seated *on* a table means, literally, to be sitting *on top of* the table.  More commonly we sit *at* the table, to eat a meal, etc.)

You can only determine which is meant from context and common idiom.  Two examples:

> I told Sally to sit anywhere she liked, so she **sat** on the table.

This implies the action of *sitting down*.

> Q: Where were the children?
>   A: There were no more chairs so they **sat** on the table.

This implies the condition of *being seated*.

Most of the time, this distinction is not important.  However, if it's not obvious, and if it is important to be clear, English speakers will use other conjugations and idiomatic expressions:

> She **is seated** at the table.
>
> The crowd was just **sitting down** when the accident happened.

There is no ambiguity with the verb "to wear".  This always implies a continuous state, and not instantaneous action.  Instead, the natural expression for the action is to "put on" an article of clothing:

> She is **putting on** her shoes.
>
> It's raining, so he is **putting on** boots and an overcoat.

Finally, here is a somewhat-related kids' joke that plays off of this kind of ambiguity:

> Q:  Why was the scarecrow so admired?
>   A: Because he was always **out standing** in his field.